How to set equivalent transformations?
I want to write down equivalent transformations and have some questions.
My MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
                  && E             &= m \times c^2 & \hspace{1.5cm} & |\div c^2\\
\Leftrightarrow{} && \frac{E}{c^2} &= m            &                & |\text{ Insert values}\\
\Leftrightarrow{} && \frac{42}{21} &= m            &                & |\text{ Calculate}\\
\Leftrightarrow{} && 2             &= m            &                & |\log\\
\Leftrightarrow{} && 2             &= m            &                & |\surd\\
\Leftrightarrow{} && 2             &= m            &                & |\times
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}

My questions:

Is it possible to change the columns from rlrlrl to for example rrll? Like my second column is always empty and my fifth only contains horizontal space. So that I could write
      & E             &= m \times c^2 & |\div c^2\\


Is it possible to define horizontal spacing between columns, so that I could move the \hspace{1.5cm} to an optional argument or a global environment?

Is the {} needed after \Leftrightarrow{}? I found that in one answer on here

Is | the correct symbol to separate the operations on the right? Or \vert, \mid or something else?

Can the spacing around | be fixed, i.e., \log is closer than \div — which I assume comes from the fact that \div (and others) is a binary operator. See also manual spaces in text mode. Note: I am not quite sure what the appropriate spacing around | would be.

Seems opinion based, but are there any recommendations for the spacing (a) after \Leftrightarrow and (b) before |?



Update:
I tried the following:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{myalignat}{%
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& \hphantom{\quad} & & & \hphantom{\qquad} &\\[-\baselineskip]
}{%
\end{alignat*}
}

\newcommand{\myvert}{\vert\medspace} %TODO remove all space produced by following input like \div, \log, ...
  
\begin{document}

Text
\hrule
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& \hphantom{\quad} & & & \hphantom{\qquad} &\\[-\baselineskip]
                && E             &= m \times c^2 && |\div c^2\\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{E}{c^2} &= m            && |\medspace\text{Insert values}\\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{42}{21} &= m            && |\medspace\text{Calculate}\\
\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && |\medspace\negthinspace\log\\
\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && |\medspace\surd\\
\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && |\medspace\times
\end{alignat*}
\hrule
Text

Using myvert:
\hrule
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& \hphantom{\quad} & & & \hphantom{\qquad} &\\[-\baselineskip]
                && E             &= m \times c^2 && \myvert\negmedspace\div c^2\\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{E}{c^2} &= m            && \myvert\text{Insert values}\\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{42}{21} &= m            && \myvert\text{Calculate}\\
\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && \myvert\negthinspace\log\\
\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && \myvert\surd\\
\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && \myvert\times
\end{alignat*}
\hrule
Text

%TODO does not work
%\begin{myalignat}
%                && E             &= m \times c^2 && |\div c^2\\
%\Leftrightarrow && \frac{E}{c^2} &= m            && |\medspace\text{Insert values}\\
%\Leftrightarrow && \frac{42}{21} &= m            && |\medspace\text{Calculate}\\
%\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && |\medspace\negthinspace\log\\
%\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && |\medspace\surd\\
%\Leftrightarrow && 2             &= m            && |\medspace\times
%\end{myalignat}

\end{document}


Take a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/witharrows .

The following solution should address most (all?) of your questions. Oh, | and \vert are equivalent; \mid isn't appropriate here.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
                &\quad&        E &= m\times c^2 &\qquad& |\text{ $\div\ c^2$}\\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{E}{c^2} &= m &     & |\text{ Insert values}\\
\Leftrightarrow && \frac{42}{21} &= m &     & |\text{ Calculate}\\
\Leftrightarrow &&             2 &= m &     & |\text{ $\log$}\\
\Leftrightarrow &&             2 &= m &     & |\text{ $\surd$}\\
\Leftrightarrow &&             2 &= m &     & |\text{ $\times$}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}


Thank you for your answer! However, surrounding everything by \text (and applying manual spacing after \div) does not clean up the code for me. I updated my question, maybe it becomes clearer what I am looking for
